# MYSQL Query with most recent results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, time-series

I want to create a query statement for MYSQL which will give me the most recent price of an item. A table contains a bunch of prices (`UnitPrice`) paired with each item (`MIL_id)`. However, I want the most recent price (`UnitPrice`) for each item (`MIL_id`). Each row also has a `ReqNum` column which increments for each entry and a `Date` column for each entry. So how can I make a query which will give me the most recent price (`UnitPrice`) with the newest `Date` or `ReqNum`?

What I have so far:

```sql
SELECT t1.VendorPtNum, t1.UnitPrice, MAX(t1.Date), MAX(t1.ReqNum), t2.MIL_id
FROM tblMatInvList t2
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseReq t1 ON t1.VendorPtNum = t2.VendPtNum
GROUP BY t2.MIL_id
HAVING MAX(t1.Date)
```

Comment: Is any row with a higher `ReqNum` value guaranteed to be more recent than rows with lower numbers?

Comment: Yes, the ReqNum increments with every entry. So higher the ReqNum the more recent the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT after your comment:

So, you have a table

**tblMatInvList**

--------------------+

VendorPtNum | MIL_id

--------------------+

and a table

**tblPurchaseReq**

---------------------------------------+

VendorPtNum | UnitPrice | Date | ReqNum

---------------------------------------+

I think you can use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblMatInvList
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT MAX(Date) as date,
              VendorPtNum
         FROM tblPurchaseReq
         GROUP BY tblPurchaseReq.VendorPtNum) prices
ON prices.VendorPtNum = tblMatInvList.VendorPtNum;
```

Comment: Sorry should have specified. the table tblMatInvList has the following columns: VendPtNum, MIL_id, and tblPurchaseReq has columns: VendorPtNum, UnitPrice, Date, ReqNum. Pretty much what you had except the other way around. However, just like the other answer, this query gives me 905 rows while there are only 140 items(MIL_id) and I want the most recent price with that item. Adding a 'GROUP BY MIL_id' gives me the first price associated with each item and not the most recent.

Comment: @Nadeemm, please, check out this new answer.

Comment: GROUP BY tblPurchaseReq.id_prod doesn't exist. If by id_prod you meant MIL_id, then MIL_id is in tblMatInvList not tblPurchaseReq.

Comment: sorry, it was "VendorPtNum".